# Setup.exe with arguments in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, processstartinfo

I don't know how to start `setup.exe` with any arguments.

Actually a try this code but something goes wrong:

```
Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
p.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\Content\Office\2013_ALL\x86\setup.exe"
p.Arguments = Application.StartupPath & "\Content\Office\2013_ALL\x86\setup.exe" & "/configure .\365HomePrem86.xml"
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
Process.Start(p)
```

Let me know if you have an idea to fix it !

I want start setup.exe like this (.bat file) :

```
start setup.exe /configure .\365HomePrem86.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.  You don't need the fullpath to setup.exe in the Arguments() property...just give it the **arguments**.  Sometimes you also need to set the WorkingDirectory() for the app to work correctly:

```
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\Content\Office\2013_ALL\x86\setup.exe"
    p.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(p.FileName)
    p.Arguments = "/configure .\365HomePrem86.xml"
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Process.Start(p)
```